# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: symfony

I am following the openclassrooms tutorial on symfony. I am now currently at the chapter "Les controleurs avec Symfony".

I try to open http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php and get this error

[NotFoundHttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVqP.png)

I suspect the error to come from AdvertController.php.
But I compared it with the given code at the tutorial. And it is exactly the same. I tried then to delete the cache but it does not function. I will open another question for that.

Here is the AdvertController.php code:

```
<?php
//src/Neo/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php
namespace Neo\PlatformBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
//use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;


class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $url= $this->get('router')->generate(
    'neo_platform_view', //first argument : path name
    array('id' => 5)
  );
    return new Response("The url of the announcement is:".$url);
}

public function viewAction($id)
{
  return new Response("Desplay of the announcment with id:".$id);
}

public function viewSlugAction($slug, $year, $_format)

  {

      return new Response(

          "We could desplay the announcment conrresponding the the slug          
'".$slug."', created in ".$year." and with the format ".$_format."."

          );

      }


}



?>
```

If you would like me to post other parts of code, please let me know. 
I have no idea, where to look at.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to dump your routes with the command `php bin/console debug:router` or `app/console` for symfony <3.0 to see if there is a route your your desired path. 
If you have the prefix /platform, your paths inside your controller are now /platform/path instead of /path.

You need a default route for your root path.

Comment: Hello Lerminou! I tried the command you mentioned but I get this message: Could not open input file: bin/console
Also in the app/config/routing.yml I have a default route defined as prefix:   /platform. Actually, I could fix my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240068/symfony-component-routing-exception-invalidparameterexception but I am curious about the debug:router. Any idea how to make it work on my console? Thanks

Comment: You need to be at the root path of your application. If you have symfony v2.X, you must use `app/console` instead of `bin/console`  (launch it just as any other console command)

Comment: Thank you Lerminou. Actually I do not know how to place my self at the root path. When I want to open my Symfony folders, I need always to write gksudo nautilus /opt/lammp/htdocs on the console to make them visible. After doing this, the terminal window does not accept other commands. I need to open another terminal window to make other actions. I will ask this question separately in another post.

Answer (score 0):

The message error is very explicit, there are not routes for "/". Try to verify your routing.yml

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the comment. I actually checked the app/config/routing.yml: Inside I had written:   prefix:   /platform  For this reason thought that Rersources/config/routing.yml only neads the path: /{page} and not path: /{page}. I am doing exactly like in the tutorial. How could I fix this? Thanks a lot!