# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ InvalidParameterException

Tags: symfony

I am following the openclassrooms tutorial on symfony. I am now currently at the chapter "Les controleurs avec Symfony".

I try to open http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/platform and I get this error

[image: InvalidParameterException]

Here is the AdvertController.php code:

```
<?php
//src/Neo/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php
namespace Neo\PlatformBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
//use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $url= $this->get('router')->generate(
        'neo_platform_view', //first argument : path name
        array('id' => 5)
      );
        return new Response("The url of the announcement is:".$url);
    }
public function viewAction($id)
{
  return new Response("Desplay of the announcment with id:".$id);
}
public function viewSlugAction($slug, $year, $_format)

      {
          return new Response(

              "We could desplay the announcment conrresponding the the slug '".$slug."', created in ".$year." and with the format ".$_format."."
          );
      }
}
?>
```

I do not understand what the error means and do not know how to fix it.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you show the route defintion for `neo_platform_view` from your routing.yml?

Comment: neo_platform_view:
        path:    /advert/{id}
        defaults:
            _controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:view
        requirements:
            id: \id+

Comment: You should probably finish one question before starting another.  I might add that if you are having this much trouble with the tutorial then you might try something else.  Like the docs?  And update your question when you add things like route definitions.  Comments don't format well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of editing the question. The tutorial is good, and it was only a little mistake. Having trouble as a beginner is normal I guess. I will keep in mind the docs though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
neo_platform_view: 
    path: /advert/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:view 
    requirements: 
        id: \d+
```

change \id+ to \d+
This should fix it. If you want to allow only numbers \d+ is the right condition.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html for further reading about requirements.

Comment: Joe, awsome! that was it! Thank you very much!